# In app purchase Developer action needed Status

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, in-app-purchase

I am working on IAP first time i have not uploaded any version on app store we have included IAP in first version. i have submitted IAP Three times but still everytime we get Developer action needed status. I have created test user and working good in sandbox env. Now if i have uploaded app on store will IAP works??

Belo code got information in sandbox env now what to do for actual working means when i uplaod app on store will it work same as sandbox mode,

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request
didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
int count = [response.products count];
if (count>0) {
    validProducts = response.products;
    validProduct = (response.products)[0];
    if ([validProduct.productIdentifier
         isEqualToString:kTutorialPointProductID]) {
        NSLog(@"All product title is --%@",validProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"All product prize is %@", validProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"All des is %@",validProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"response products is %@", validProduct.productIdentifier);
        NSLog(@"AL*****%@", validProduct);
}

} else {
    UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle:@"Not Available"
                        message:@"No products to purchase"
                        delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                        otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [tmp show];
}    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Goto iTunes connect- >Manage APPs -> Manage In app Purchase -> Select your in app purchase

Make sure the product Cleared for Sale Yes and add screenshot for review.

Make sure IN- APP Purchase Details have Proper Display Name and  Description

In iTunes connect- > Manage APPs -> View Details of the app.

Below Demo Account Information (Optional)

There is IN APP PURCHASE.You need to select the appropriate in app and save before You proceed with Ready to Submit.

Answer (score -1):

if your in app purchase works fine with SandBox account then it is working fine !!!